# OGR Header Field Length

Tags: python, header, ogr

I'm trying to convert a csv file to an ESRI Shapefile with OGR in Python.
The problem is obviously that my header entries are too long for the default field size:

```
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'SEEHOEHE [m]' to 'SEEHOEHE ['
```

I want to loop over all header elements (the number of columns in my csv file is unknown) and create new fields in the shapefile - "on the fly", so to speak:

```
for i in range(0,len(header)):
    layer_out.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn(header[i], ogr.OFTString))
```

works fine, but with the header entries cut off (this is problematic, because i need to address them later on). Is there a way to define the header entry size in the same step? I tried it with `SetField(32)`, but I fear this alters only the size for the table entries.
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The limitation of 10 characters is a fixed property of the format. Perhaps you can bypass it by also addressing them with this cutoff, eg `header[i][:10]` etc.

Comment: Thank you, that's how I solved the issue finally in order not to get into trouble all the time...anyways, this limitation seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: The `Shapefile` format is long overdue and only still popular because it offers great interoperability. Perhaps recent alternatives like the `GeoPackage` from OGC will catch on in the near future.